# Equation of the plane tangent to a given surface at a given point

Tags: calculus

I'm asked to find the equation of the plane tangent to the function $f(x,y)=y^2e^{4x}$ at $Q=(0,-1,f(0,-1))$.

However, I'm pretty unsure how to find it given that the function has two variables, and the point is three-dimensional.

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, so it's graph has points of 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

One generally speaks of *tangency to the graph* of a function, not to the function itself as you say. The *graph* of a function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$,
$$ \operatorname{gph}(f) = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R\ |\ z = f(x,y) \} ,$$
is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$, and evidently $Q \in \operatorname{gph}(f)$.